Realtime issue with supabase custom oauth integration
I have a project in supabase for a react native mobile client. I use a custom oauth flow where a service called autolab manages all my auth and gives me a token which I then convert into my own jwt on the backend. I use the jwt when initializing the supabase client and everything was working fine until I started doing realtime. I have proper RLS policies in place based on the custom JWT which enables me to read/write/delete but when it comes to realtime, only DELETE events get emitted and not INSERT.
So this is how I mint my own JWT on the backend:
const jwtPayload = {
      sub: autolabUser.email,
      aud: "authenticated",
      role: "authenticated",
      iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
      exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 7200, // autolab token is valid for 2 hours
    };

   const supabaseJwt = jwt.sign(jwtPayload, process.env.SUPABASE_JWT_SECRET, {
      // expiresIn: "2h",
    });

Im just using this JWT to initialize supabase using the Authorization header:
createClient(
      process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
      process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
      {
        global: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
          },
        },
      }
    );

When I was testing realtime events, I inserted something onto my table and found out it was not emitted. I have two policies in place for my delete, insert and read:
create policy "Enable read for all authenticated users"
on "public"."queue_entries"
to public
using (
  ((auth.jwt() ->> 'role'::text) = 'authenticated'::text)
);

create policy "Enable insert for all authenticated users"
on "public"."queue_entries"
to public
with check (
  (( SELECT (auth.jwt() ->> 'role'::text)) = 'authenticated'::text)
);

I'm not sure where to go from here as I couldn't find any good online resources for this problem either, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!
